# Possible products from anion analyses

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, analytical-chemistry

What are possible products from these two anion analyses?

1. The nitrite test, reacting diphenylamine with a nitrite:

$$
\ce{(C6H5)2NH + NO2- -> ?}
$$

2. The sulphite test, reacting potassium permanganate with a sulphite:

$$
\ce{KMnO4 + SO3^{2-} -> ?}
$$

Answer (score 2):

1. Under acidic conditions, a blue colour is observed. This results from the formation of N,N'-diphenylbenzidine. In the course of the reaction, diphenylamine is oxidized to a quinoid radical which subsequently adds to another molecule of diphenylamine.
2. Under slightly acidic conditions, bleaching of the solution is observed. Sulfite is oxidized to sulfate while $\ce{MnO4-}$ is reduced to $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$.

Comment: No...i want the full reaction

Comment: @NeilRoy With other words: Do my homework. No, because... NO!

Comment: Well can you please give me the reaction. It is not homework ... it is given in my practical chemistry book but no reactions were given with it! So please help